# Equation of a plane parallel to $x$-axis

Tags: geometry

I have a plane that is parallel to the $x$-axis and intersects the $y$-axis at the point $130$ at an angle $\alpha$. I just wanted to check this is right for a colleague as I'm a bit rusty.

One point is the $y$-intercept $(0,130,0)$. The $z$-intercept is $(0,0,130\tan\alpha)$. Another point that lies on the plane could be $(1,130,0)$ as it's parallel to the $x$-axis. So two vectors in the plane could be $\langle0,-130, 130\tan\alpha\rangle$ and $\langle1,0,0\rangle$ with cross-product $\langle 0, 130\tan\alpha, 130\rangle$.

So the equation of the plane should be $$0(x-0)+130\tan\alpha(y-130)+130(z-0)=0$$
$$\implies y + \dfrac{z}{\tan\alpha} = 130.$$

I can't spot a mistake here, but my colleague says this doesn't seem to work with his experiment. Many thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that a plane perpendicular to the $x$ axis is parallel to the $y-z$ plane. Or not?

Comment: @EmilioNovati ah, my mistake. I meant parallel to the $x$-axis.

Comment: Possibly your $\alpha$ is your colleague's $-\alpha$...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mistake in the answer.

Notice, there is a simple approach to find the equation of a plane in the intercept form.

The given plane intercepts the x-axis at infinity (i.e. parallel to the x-axis), y-axis at $(0, 130, 0)$ & the z-axis at $(0, 0, 130\tan \alpha)$,

then intercepts of the given plane with the coordinate axes x-, y- & z-axis are $a=\infty$, $b=130$ & $c=130\tan \alpha$  respectively hence equation of the plane is given by the intercept form as follows
$$\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$$ Now, setting the corresponding values, we get 
$$\frac{x}{\infty}+\frac{y}{130}+\frac{z}{130\tan \alpha}=1$$
$$0+\frac{y}{130}+\frac{z}{130\tan \alpha}=1$$
$$\color{red}{y+\frac{z}{\tan \alpha}=130}$$
Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The process you've outlined here is correct, and I didn't catch any arithmetic errors. Therefore I guess that the solution you have given is correct.

I do however, have qualms with with $\alpha$. What do we know about it and how is it measured.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I meant parallel to the $x$-axis

Comment: For the purposes of the experiment, the plane is actually a phone. So we can imagine it in one quadrant touching that point on the $y$-axis and the angle \alpha changes as you rotate the phone.

Comment: So one corner of the phone is fixed to the point (0,130,0)? It seems to me that either the equation given should work, or the same equation with $-\alpha$ should work. These would cover the two ways fix the phone to the point (you could fix the left corner or the right corner of the phone and these would alter the way you measure $\alpha$ )

Comment: I thought so too, I guess there must be a mistake in the experiment somewhere. Many thanks for verifying!